# generate dynamic insert queries from mysql tables using php

Tags: mysql, codeigniter

i have a `courses_material` Mysql database. It has many tables like

```
courses, lessons, exercises, quizzes, exams, questions
```

i'm running my application in 2 servers, one is the TEST SERVER and other is the PRODUCTION SERVER

basically we will create material of a course XYZ in test server and  check it in the application for look and feel, course content etc..

If everything is fine then we will move the entire material of course XYZ to production database.

Test server may contain any other courses.
I want to select a course and dump all the data of that course into .sql file in the form of insert queries. Then i can run the sql file on the production site.

I have to do this using PHP, i'm using codeigniter (MVC) framework.
What is the best way to do it?. 
i  need some suggestions

Answer (score 0):

CodeIgniter has a db utility class with a [backup function](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/utilities.html#backup). You could try using that or take the source and manipulate it to fit your needs.

Comment: Thanks sgcharlie. i look into dbutill calss, but i'm unable to get how its generating insert quries.

Comment: Check out the `_backup` function in `mysql_utility.php`. Near the very bottom of the page, you'll find the `INSERT` statements that are added to the file. I think modifying this function may be your best bet.